# Does Angular.JS have a module loader or do I need to use script tags?

Tags: angularjs, javascript

I am using Angular JS. I wish to put unrelated code (ie, which is not a factory, service, controler, etc) in additional, separate modules, in a similar way one would with AMD or CommonJS.

At the time of writing, a search for 'Angular.JS make new module' using Google does not return any documentation on making Angular.JS modules.

I have a found a post on the Angular.JS Google Group that seems to indicate that [instead of loading dependencies dynamically like other module systems, in Angular.JS dependencies must be inserted as additional script tags](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/lebEHY-JzW4).

1. Is there any documentation on making Angular modules (which is not limited to controllers, services, or other angular concepts)?
2. Is the statement about script tags true? Do I need to manually add script tags for every module I may use?

Answer (score 1):

Looking further into the various Angular boilerplate apps, **apps manually load every part of their apps via script tags**. Unlike other systems, Angular 'modules' don't take care of actually loading dependencies, they just inject them once already loaded.